# How can I fetch before or after n rows after a particular column value in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a result set from which I want to get next n rows (or previous n rows) after (before) the row that matches a particular cell value.

So for example, here is my data:

```
A    B   C
1   10   2018-11-01
2   20   2018-10-31
3   30   2018-10-30
4   40   2018-10-29
5   50   2018-10-28
6   60   2018-10-27
```

I am interested to get 3 rows before the row where C=2018-10-28 (date type), including C=2018-10-28 row, so my output should be

```
 A    B   C
3   30   2018-10-30
4   40   2018-10-29
5   50   2018-10-28
```

I tried loc but it needs index and so this raises error : `df2 = df2.loc[:C].tail(3)` as `TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to int`.

Comment: @DeepamPatel, I don't think that's a good dup target for this post. The point is we don't know *in advance* the two dates required for slicing.

Answer (score 1):

Check `dtypes` in `df`: if `df.dtypes` of `C` columns is not datetime, convert it into datetime:

```
df.dtypes
Out[46]:
B     int64
C    object
dtype: object

df['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df['C'])
df.dtypes
Out[48]:
B             int64
C    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Now 'C' columns is comparable with  datetime-formatted strings:

```
target_date = "2018-10-28"
df[df['C'] >= target_date].tail(3)
    B          C
A
3  30 2018-10-30
4  40 2018-10-29
5  50 2018-10-28
```

But in more general case (there are more than one target column and data is unordered) you could use a following approach:

```
df
A    B          C

0   10 2018-09-10
1   20 2018-07-11
2   20 2018-06-12
3   30 2018-07-13
4   50 2018-10-28
5   10 2018-11-01
6   20 2018-10-31
7   30 2018-10-30
8   40 2018-10-29
9   50 2018-10-28
10  60 2018-10-27

index = df[df['C'] == '2018-10-28'].index
index
Out:
Int64Index([4, 9], dtype='int64', name=0)
```

Use `slice` and `.iloc` to fetch targets:

```
slices = [slice(i, i-3, -1) for i in indicies]
slices
Out: [slice(4, 1, -1), slice(9, 6, -1)]

pd.concat([df.iloc[sl] for sl in slices])
    B          C
A
4  50 2018-10-28
3  30 2018-07-13
2  20 2018-06-12
9  50 2018-10-28
8  40 2018-10-29
7  30 2018-10-30
```

Resulting frame is not sorted, but it'll be easy to fix. This approach works only for a numerical index, but in it's absence you can just add it with `pd.reset_index()`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am interested to get 3 rows before the row where C = 2018-10-28

First find the index via [`pd.Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html), then slice using [`pd.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), which supports integer positional indexing:

```
idx = df['C'].eq('2018-10-28').idxmax()
res = df.iloc[idx-2: idx+1]

print(res)

#    A   B          C
# 2  3  30 2018-10-30
# 3  4  40 2018-10-29
# 4  5  50 2018-10-28
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something

```
s = StringIO("""
A    B   C
1   10   2018-11-01
2   20   2018-10-31
3   30   2018-10-30
4   40   2018-10-29
5   50   2018-10-28
6   60   2018-10-27""")

final = pd.read_csv(s, sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
final['C] = pd.to_datetime(final['C])
```

final

```
  A   B           C
0  1  10  2018-11-01
1  2  20  2018-10-31
2  3  30  2018-10-30
3  4  40  2018-10-29
4  5  50  2018-10-28
5  6  60  2018-10-27

final.loc[final[final['C'] == '2018-10-28'].index[0]-2:final[final['C'] == '2018-10-28' ].index[0]]
```

**Output**

```
   A   B           C
2  3  30  2018-10-30
3  4  40  2018-10-29
4  5  50  2018-10-28
```